# Ubuntu 15.04 destroys my Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04

I have ubuntu 15.04, my Wi-Fi adapter is ralink rt5390.

lshw -C network output:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 00
   serial: e0:06:e6:9f:c0:84
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.19.0-25-generic firmware=0.34 ip=192.168.1.93 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:dea00000-dea0ffff
```

**The problem:** When I download something, or watch video online (like youtube) after some time (like 10-30 mins) I lose wifi connection, despite the fact, that GUI shows that I'm still connected, but when I try to reconnect it won't. And rebooting, re-enabling wifi/networking won't help.

**Destroys?** Yep, destroys my routers wifi o.O I can not connect to same wifi when I boot up my windows 7, or when I try with my android phone. It just does not connect. Although wired connection works perfectly to my other always connected pc. To fix wifi I have to reboot my router.

I'm using asus x54c laptop, I have windows 7 on this laptop with dualboot and tried openSuse, both OS'es does no harm to my wifi. What is wrong with ubuntu?

Comment: it possibly that not ubuntu is guilty but your router itself? did u check tha variant?

Comment: Check your router with another computer and your laptop with another router that shall help determine which is at fault.

Comment: Well might be router, but why there is no problem with openSuse or windows 7? What ubuntu does differently that causes my router to fail?

Comment: p.s. android devices does not fail wifi either.

Comment: to see the real problem you should check routers system logs, some routers allow to do this from the stock, some not, then you r less lucky. Check ubuntu with another router....btw, situation you describe very close describe the way when router "hangs".

Comment: Only interesting lines in log: http://pastebin.com/Pv7sbJ0z

Well... I've did some search and people who uses same ISP and router has similar (while downloading something or watching videos disconnects) problems. But it's really strange, that I have this problem only with ubuntu... And it happened few months back, while I'm using same router for 2-4 years...

Comment: Well it's definitely something's up with ubuntu... All day I watched TV series today with same laptop but windows 7 and nothing... wifi is working... No disconnects, no nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Partial solution

I've booted into old kernel version (3.19.0-15 to be exact) and wifi is back to normal! No disconnects while watching video, no disconnects while downloading files, everything works!

Comment: p.s. even this method does not work perfectly, but wifi connection lasts at least for a couple of hours. Anyways, untill this is fixed I'm on openSuse which just works. :?